# What's the difference between "lad" and "mate" in British English?

Tags: meaning, differences, nouns, british-english

Can "lad" only be used to address a male, while "mate" both male and female?

Comment: Yes. Lad: A boy or man. Mate: Informal term for a friend of the same sex.

Comment: Except for *stable lad*, which despite the existence in English of *stable girl,* can refer to those of either sex who work with racehorses.

Comment: Both words are well explained with etymology and more on most online resources.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Lad* describes only a male, and it tends to be used as a vocative only in the northern half of England. In informal conversation, *mate* has traditionally been used only of males as well, but is now used to refer to females as well, and to a mixed group of males and females.

Comment: She's one of the lads?

Comment: Who are the lads? The feminine of _lad_ is _ladette_.

Comment: That, too, but a _ladette_ is a young lady who behaves just as disgracefully as her male counterparts.

Comment: So only the female of the species (go look for a) mate? *2.
a fellow member or joint occupant of a specified thing. 
"his tablemates"*; *One of a matched pair: the mate to this glove. 2. A spouse*

Answer (score 3):

***Lad*** is another name for a boy or a young man.

I suspect that *lad* is becoming increasingly rare to hear, I might be wrong, but I think this word still resists in the north of England, especially in Yorkshire. The female equivalent of lad is **lassie** or ***lass***.

*Lad* is often used as an affectionate term as in

> He's a good lad, his heart's in the right place.

Whereas ***mate*** is an informal word meaning friend, and can be used for both men and women. The following expressions are clichéd but will give you an idea of how the word is used in conversation:

> I'm going down the pub with me mates (more likely said by a man.)

and

> Me and my mates had a great time down at the local (could be said by either a man or woman.)
>
> She's my best mate, I love her to bits

Comment: Mari-Lou A, *North England* should be *Northern England*.

Comment: @Tristan I don't consider North England to be strictly incorrect, but it's true that northern England and the North of England are more common. So many thanks. Although I doubt this was the real reason for the downvote :)

Comment: I don't know about the downvote. It wasn't from me.

Comment: I have other stack exchange accounts.....  didn't think about getting on for English but did so, just to up vote this, because I am particularly annoyed by people that down-vote for no particular reason.  True story.

Answer (score 2):

Used in the traditional macho form of 'On Fridays I go to the pub with me mates/the lads/the boys', I feel sure there were at one time regional variations. 'Lad' is still associated with the north of England and Scotland, an accompaniment of 'lass' or 'lassie'. (My wife was delighted many years ago in Edinburgh, when an older gentleman, of whom she had asked directions, called her 'lassie')

Professor of Socio-Linguistics, Peter Trudgill, in his work on the the Norfolk Dialect, and in stressing the sudden cut-off of Norfolk, in the area close to The Wash, has put a marker on the village of Terrington St Clement. In a Terrington pub, Trudgill argues, they will be speaking the Norfolk dialect and the young men will be called 'boys' (pronounced 'buuys'.) About 7 miles down the road and across the Great Ouse in Sutton Bridge, the pub company will be speaking a distinctively northern dialect and the young men will be called 'lads'.

That is not to say that 'lad' is not used in the south of England, in context. 'He's a good lad'.

'Mate' I feel sure originated, in this sense, in Cockney English, though it has a long and complex history, and is now heard far and wide. It is also extensively used in compounds, such as 'flat-mate', 'dining-mate', 'drinking-mate' etc

It should be borne in mind that there are many other meanings to these words. Calling someone a 'lad' can be in the sense of a boisterously macho young man 'Tony was a bit of a lad for the women' (ODE).

'Mate' has many meanings, including as a rank in the Merchant Navy, as an officer subordinate to the Master, e.g. A First Mate. It is also used occupationally such as in 'plumber's mate'

This is potentially a vast subject.